# Someone put torrc other one torcc. Why?

Tags: configuration, mac

I couldn't find torcc or torrc, at anywhere. I use a Catalina Mac version 10.15.7, but i can't find anyone that file.
Someone could help me?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-editing-torrc/

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, the `torrc` is in the Tor Browser Data directory at `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor`.

- Note the Library folder is hidden on newer versions of macOS. To navigate to this folder in Finder, select "Go to Folder..." in the "Go" menu.
- Then type `~/Library/Application Support/` in the window and click Go.